# Block invoke dispatch crash iOS 7

Tags: ios

Using dispatch manager in my iOS app for 2 years now. Ever since iOS 7 strange crashes are happening when using it the same way. I have a switch what updates a value in the database (CoreData) and when done i do a reload. Sometimes when switching the control to on or off the app crashes on block invoke of the refresh system. But only since iOS 7..

What can i do about this?

Error:

```
libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release:
0x3b231d70:  push   {r4, r7, lr}
0x3b231d72:  mov    r4, r0
0x3b231d74:  add    r7, sp, #4
0x3b231d76:  ldr    r1, [r4, #12]
0x3b231d78:  blx    r1
0x3b231d7a:  mov    r0, r4
0x3b231d7c:  pop.w  {r4, r7, lr}
0x3b231d80:  b.w    0x3b2508a0                ; _Block_release$shim
```

Comment: Perhaps a memory management problem (overrelease), but are you using ARC?

Comment: Its specifically crashing at this line:

Comment: NSMutableArray *bgSteps = [[[questionnaire.step allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:alphaSort]] mutableCopy];